# か細く暗い (Usage of く to describe adjective?)

Tags: grammar, adjectives

みんなの声は、か細く暗い。

When linking two adjectives, why does this sentence use an adverb (か細く) to describe another adjective (暗い) ? Shouldn't it be the te-form instead to represent "and"?

From what I can understand from か細く暗い, it basically means "Fragile Darkness"? "Everyone's voice is fragile darkness" which does not make sense. Everyone's voice is fragile and dark seems to fit more.

Could anyone clarify this? Thank you!